# Upper bound on matrix vector multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

For a matrix $A$, let $\|A\|_2$ denote the spectral norm (operator norm with euclidean norm used in both spaces). And for a vector $x$, let $\|x\|_2$ denote the euclidean norm.

---

Is the following inequality correct?

$
\|Ax\|_2 \leq \|A\|_2 \|x\|_2
$

using the first property listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Properties).

---

I have seen from a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1361853/762889), they have the inequality

$
\|Ax\|_2 \leq \|A\|_F \|x\|_2
$

which is not as good in general as from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Examples_of_norm_equivalence) $\|A\|_2 \leq \|A\|_F \leq \sqrt{r}\|A\|_2$

Comment: Yes, the first inequality is correct.